# Add the same product more than once, in an order from the admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to be able to add the same product more than once within an order in WooCommerce.

This is the scenario.

I create an order manually from the admin panel of Woocommerce, and I need to be able to add the same product N times to this order.

Basically I need something like what this snippet does, but for the backend instead of for the frontend cart.

```
function separate_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
      $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime() . rand() );
      $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

      return $cart_item_data;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'separate_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );
```

Any suggestion to get this?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In order to duplicate product N times you can add any woocommerce clone duplicate plugin.

You can download a plugin on [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-easy-duplicate-product/) to accomplish your task

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't need to duplicate a product.

I need to be able to include the same product multiple times in the same order, through the admin panel.

Comment: If you let me know your purpose or target then i might help you.

Comment: I create orders manually from the woocommerce backend.

I manually add products, through the add product button.

But when I try to add a product that already exists in the order lines, woocommerce does not add it.

My goal is to be able to add the same product multiple times in different order lines.

Sorry about my English... have I explained myself?

Comment: If of all woocommerce will not allow you to create same product again. However, it will allow you to add multiple orders for same product. If each order has different required, then you might look for product varients which includes, size, color, and other attributes.